# sql join 2 rows in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
Name   Type     Value
---------------------
mike   phone    123    
mike   address  nyc    
bob    address  nj    
bob    phone    333
```

I want to have the result like this:

```
name  value  value
-------------------
mike  nyc    123
bob   nj     333
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it is called a self-join. the trick is to use aliases.

```
select 
    address.name,
    address.value as address,
    phone.value as phone
from
    yourtable as address left join
    yourtable as phone on address.name = phone.name
where address.type = 'address' and
      (phone.type is null or phone.type = 'phone')
```

The query assumes that each name has an address, but phone numbers are optional.

Comment: Was typing this in (almost verbatim) when your answer showed up.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.name AS name, phone, address
    FROM (SELECT name, value AS phone FROM mytable WHERE type = "phone") AS a
    JOIN (SELECT name, value AS address FROM mytable WHERE type = "address") AS b
    ON(a.name = b.name);
```